# SparkJava JOOQ dependency injection with Guice

Tags: java, guice, jooq, spark-java

I am writing simple *CRUD* application which would fetch person records from *database* and I'm using *SparkJava* framework I have working code which fetches records from *database* but I would want to extract *JOOQ* **DSLContext** code and inject it as a bean and initialize it in another class in order to have more cleaner code, but I'm not sure how to achieve it here's main method which currently hold everything:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(BankApiApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"));
    ds.setDriverClassName(properties.getProperty("db.driver"));
    ds.setUrl(properties.getProperty("db.url"));
    ds.setUsername(properties.getProperty("db.username"));
    ds.setPassword(properties.getProperty("db.password"));

    final ConnectionProvider cp = new DataSourceConnectionProvider(ds);
    final Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration()
            .set(cp)
            .set(SQLDialect.H2)
            .set(new ThreadLocalTransactionProvider(cp, true));
    final DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(configuration);
    final JSONFormat format = new JSONFormat().format(true).header(false).recordFormat(JSONFormat.RecordFormat.OBJECT);

    port(8080);

    get("/persons", (request, response) -> {
        return ctx.select().from(Person.PERSON).fetch().formatJSON();
    });
}
```

How I could extract code which initializes **Datasource** and configures **DSLContext** and instead I could just inject **DSLContext** or some kind of **DSLContextHolder** and do querying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in general, you want to inject *the highest-level object you can*. This is related to [the Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), which in short says that a component can know about its direct dependencies, but it shouldn't know about those dependencies' dependencies.

In your case, you're really only using `DSLContext` (`ctx`). [A note here: your code has a lot of two-letter names - it's pretty hard to follow. It would be easier if you wrote out e.g. `ctx -> dslContext`, `cp -> connectionProvider`]. This means you really only want your method to know about the `DSLContext`, not its dependencies. Therefore, it would be good to pull the following out into a module, then inject *just a `DSLContext`*:

1. `Configuration`
2. `ConnectionProvider`
3. `Properties`
4. `BasicDataSource`

If all these things are only used in this one `main()`, you can write a single `Provider` to return a `DSLContext`. If some of these are used in multiple places (for more than instantiating this `main()`'s `DSLContext`), then they can go in their own `Provider`s. For example, here's what a `Provider` for a `DSLContext` would look like, if `Configuration` was placed in its own `Provider`:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    // other providers
    // ...

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public DSLContext dslContext(Configuration configuration) {
        return SL.using(configuration);
    }
}
```

Then, in your `main()`, you would write:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(yourModule());
DSLContext myContext = injector.getInstance(DSLContext.class);

// ... use it
```